# How to use Excel Formulas in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to put this formula into VBA.

> =IFERROR(AP24728<0,(NETWORKDAYS(B24728,AQ24728,'N:#Abe\Report PU\Desember[Report PU 05 Des 2016.xlsx]Holidays'!$A$2:$A$69))-1)

Comment: Please give more details. All your question currently says is that you have an issue with VBA, and it shows an Excel formula. What are you trying to do?  What is not working?

Comment: I want to put this formula into VBA, any sample coding ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Excel formula in VBA you have two choices: you can either `Evaluate` the function string as in @YowE3K's example given here, or alternatively you can use the `WorksheetFunction` method to perform most Excel functions. The `Evaluate` method is best if you want to do a fixed formula like your example suggests and return the result in VBA, the `WorksheetFunction` method allows you to specify the arguments in VB language, which (in my opinion) is better for a dynamic function (there is however a trade-off in terms of speed if you're trying to do this multiple times, such as iterating over a range of cells etc.) However, since you have another function embedded in the `IfError`, you'd need to nest another `WorksheetFunction` within the `IfError` one, like below:

```
WorksheetFunction.IfError([expression], WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays([date from], [date to], [holidays]))
```

However, it is not clear from your post what you want to do. The key thing here would be to provide some further information about what you are trying to do overall - i.e. what is the 'big picture' that you're trying to achieve? Do you just want to test the value in one cell? Will this be something that you need to repeat for multiple cells? Why do you need to do this in VBA, when you could much more easily use the formula in a worksheet?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your answer to "What are you trying to do?" of "I want to put this formula into VBA", some sample code might be:

```
Dim result As Variant
result = Evaluate("IFERROR(AP24728<0,(NETWORKDAYS(B24728,AQ24728,'N:#Abe\Report PU\Desember[Report PU 05 Des 2016.xlsx]Holidays'!$A$2:$A$69))-1)")
```

If you provide additional details in your question, I can expand on this answer, or someone else may come up with a much better way.